# Videos flicker during play back 2 GPUs Multi-Monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, firefox, nvidia-graphics-card, sli

I have a multi-screen desktop. I have 4 screens in total. Three of them are in NVIDIA Surround setup. My issue is when playing any video on my right most screen the video will blink (only the video not the screen or the web page) however it does not blink when I move the video to the other screens in the Surround or on the extra screen. This happens with any video service.

How the screens are connected to the GPU's 
 [[image: screen Diagram]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUuip.png)

I am running:

- Intel DX79SR extreme series board
- Intel i7-3930k CPU 3.20GHz
- 64 GB RAM
- 2 Geforce GTX 670 2GB GPU in SLI
- 4 Acer V246HL monitors
- 1 Targa LCDTV
- 64 bit Windows 7 Professional
- FireFox browser

Comment: I ran GPU-Z I did not notice any strange spikes or falls during any of the blinking

Comment: Which is the primary monitor? Also I assume this is extended mode?

Comment: Also what happens when you attach 3 displays to 2nd and 1 display to the 1st GPU

Comment: What is the connector used for the Targa (4th monitor where I understand is the problem)? It looks from the drawing like the other 3 monitors are on 2 DPI ports as 2-on-1 and 1-on-1.

Comment: The three Monitors plugged in through DVI(2,3,4) are in NVIDIA surround and are the main screens. The forth is plugged in through DisplayPort

Comment: The targa is my TV I actual just unplugged it. It was just setting there being unused.

Answer (score 0):

You might be overloading the capacities of the first GTX 670.

Try connecting the Targa TV over HDMI on the second GTX 670.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while using  `Ubuntu 22.04 LTS`. I have 2 `RTX card` with that one GPU connected with `2 DisplayPort and 1 HDMI`, another with `2 DisplayPort` only. All these 5 monitors are 4K. Among these two displays, one display was randomly on and off. I had the up-to-date GPU driver. So what I did, set up the blinking display as primary display, and the blinking frequency is much less, I can say around 20% than the previous time.